# What are the current statics of the flu globally since december 2019 until today?

Tags: virus, statistics, influenza

I can only find the current statics for the US that says "Between 36 million and 51 million people have been stricken with the flu as of March 7, according to the latest CDC data." link: https://www.advisory.com/daily-briefing/2020/03/17/flu-update

I would like the global numbers of how many flu cases there are in the world since december 2019 until today.

Comment: Since it's not a pandemic you're talking about, the world data might not be centralized by anyone, but try the WHO. https://www.who.int/influenza/surveillance_monitoring/updates/latest_update_GIP_surveillance/en/ Also, this q is at best suitable for Med SE.

Comment: For 2018-19 the review was [published](https://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/handle/10665/326242/WER9432-en-fr.pdf?ua=1) in Aug '19; so if you don't want to do the accounting yourself (from their weekly reports), you'd probably have to wait until Aug this year for their summary.